# ¿ Es posible la instalación de Smarty PHP en local?

Tags: php, smarty

Recientemente comencé a trabajar con una página web, la misma trabaja con Smarty, sin embargo no quiero tocar nada de la propia web y como no he trabajado nunca con PHP ni el propio Smarty, pues estoy tratando de trabajar de forma local mediante Xampp, sin embargo no me reconoce Smarty. Porque entiendo que desde local, no esta instalado. Mi pregunta es, es posible? Puesto que todo lo que veo es en base a los directorios del servidor.

Gracias.

Comment: Si, smarty puedes trabajarlo localmente. Lo normal sería que las librerías del proyecto estuvieran asociadas a composer. Entonces deberías tener los archivos `composer.json` y `composer.lock` en tu maquina local y ejecutar `composer install` para que se descargue todas las librerías que requieres.

Comment: Lo ideal es incorporar Smarty usando Composer, como dice @Pipe. Pero, como estás sobre una web ya existente, se supone que ésta ya tiene Smarty de alguna manera. Es posible que tengas que reconfigurar rutas, porque quizá se están usando rutas absolutas a la hora de cargar Smarty. No obstante, cuando dices que "no me reconoce" Smarty ¿qué pasa exactamente? ¿se llega a ver algo de la web, o te da error o algo, quizá un error fatal? Esa información ayudaría a saber qué pasa. En cualquier caso, la respuesta a tu pregunta es **sí**, ya que instalarlo es incorporar sus archivos y cargarlo desde PHP.